# Strange issue happening with getView in Android

Tags: android

I call a web service and parse the JSON response into an object called venueList

Some of the returned venues are 'featured', meaning in the list view they get a different background to stand out from the non-featured venues.

After I get the data I iterate through the data, stick the featured items at the top and then add the non-featured venues.

Once the data is sorted the way I want it I use a custom ArrayAdapter like so:

```
ArrayAdapter<Listing> customerAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<Listing>(ViewHappyHoursListingsActivity.this, 
    R.layout.list_item, R.id.name, venueListsWithFeaturedAtBeginning) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView listingID = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.listingID);
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView location = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView runningTime = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.runningtime);
        TextView distance = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.distance);

        // Change UI if this listing is a featured one
        if(getItem(position).featured)
        {
            name.setText(getItem(position).venueName);
            Log.d("Setting textview to black in position:", String.valueOf(position));
            name.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        }
        else
        {
            name.setText(getItem(position).venueName);
        }

        listingID.setText("" + getItem(position).listingID);
        location.setText(getItem(position).venueLocation);
        runningTime.setText(getItem(position).runningTime);
        distance.setText(getItem(position).distanceForUI);

        return view;
    }
};
setListAdapter(customerAdapter);
```

Based on the data in venueListsWithFeaturedAtBeginning only the top 2 items should have the black background. There are 8 items in the list view and the first and second have a black background as expected but so do the sixth and seventh

The output looks like:

```
ListItem1: Black background
ListItem2: Black background
ListItem3: White background
ListItem4: White background
ListItem5: White background
ListItem6: Black background
ListItem7: Black background
ListItem8: White background
```

The Log.d() line outputs

D/Setting name textview to black in position:﹕ 0
D/Setting name textview to black in position:﹕ 1

and nothing else.

Does anyone know why this behaviour is happening?

Comment: Please don't use `"" +` to convert to String, it makes my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The views are getting recycled (i.e. items 6 and 7 reuse the same `convertView` as 1 and 2), so you need to remove the background from views that do not need it. Add

```
name.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

to your `else` branch.